# Adjusting for selection bias in a structural topic model

Tags: latent-variable, topic-models, latent-class, selection-bias

I want to build a structural topic model that adjusts for selection bias into the sample of entities about whom documents are written. I wanted to use the `stm` R package to do this. Unfortunately, there is no sampling-weight argument in the `stm` function so far as I can see. For this reason, I am considering writing my own implementation of structural topic models that allows for a sampling weight. Maybe that isn't necessary. What are my options within the `stm` R package framework? Is there another method I could apply post hoc, such as post-stratification *a la* multilevel regression and post-stratification (MrP)? Thanks.

**Edit:** For now, I have decided to go with including a basis spline for the propensity score as a continuous stratification variable in the topic prevalence model. This will, so far as I know, not directly apply an adjustment to anything aside from the topic prevalence model coefficients.